# Unable to send email from Ghost

Tags: node.js, email, forgot-password

I have been wrestling with this for days. I am exasperated in extremis.

I have a hosted Ghost blog at ***umquhile.org/kelpie***. It has been working fine. Somehow I locked myself out of my account. 75,000 posts say I need to set up email so I can click on "Forgotten Password". I have gone by 12,000 posts (okay, a SLIGHT exaggeration) that show how to do it. First, Ghost's tutorial flat does not work. I have tried vanilla *sendmail* (which is expected not to work), *Mailgun*, *Sendgrid*, and *Gmail*. I have gone over my configuration repeatedly.

I get different error messages depending on how I set it up. Sometimes I have gotten a 535 - invalid login credentials, sometimes all recipients rejected; right now I am getting "Cannot read property 'count' of undefined", whatever that one is. Can someone tell me if there is a problem with this configuration. Or how-the-deuce to get email to work in Ghost.

I should note that I have restarted node.js each time I made a change.

```
config = {
// ### Production
// When running Ghost in the wild, use the production environment
// Configure your URL and mail settings here
production: {
    url: 'http://umquhile.org/kelpie',
    mail: {
        service: 'Gmail',
        fromaddress: ‘xxxx@gmail.com',
        transport: 'SMTP',
        options: {
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            secureConnection: true,
            port: 465,
            auth:  {
                user: ‘xxxx@gmail.com',
                pass: ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxxx’
            }
        }
    },
```

For what is's worth, I read that Ghost uses Bcrypt hash for passwords. I have used an online Bcrypt generator to hash a password I provided. I copied the string and pasted it into the password field of my admin user in Mysql. That did not work because my account just flat remains locked.

Answer (score 0):

And as soon as I post to stackoverflow, it hits me!!

I went into the database, via phpmyadmin, and found the field *status*

It was set to *locked*

I cleared the field, saved the change, and tadaaa! I am now able to access my blog once again. Sorry for the nuisance post! The answer JUST occurred to me.